# What are the best practices for DTOs when it comes to entity <-> DTO conversion methods?

Tags: java, gwt

Should the conversion methods be stored in the DTO ? ( like in the tutorial for hibernate+gwt on gwtproject.com) Or should i make a a static class with converter methods? When i send a DTO over the wire using asynccallback then is  the method code sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the DTO is to separate the model from the data transported on the wire. If you have the conversion methods in the DTO you couple these 2 together.

When would it be problematic? Let's say for example you have a jar that contains dto classes that both server and client use. In this case you can use the same jar in your build process for both sides. But if you couple the model to the DTO you'll have to add jars to your model classes in the client tier.

I recommend a decoupled class for converting. It can be either with static calls or instance-calls if you have specific data for different conversion (for example - different injected services).